# Convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, sql, date, datetime, java.util.date

I am trying to get date in my database that have format like this "dd/MM/yyyy" and compare them to get latest date..

I was surprised to find that it couldn't do the conversion implicitly or explicitly - but I don't even know how I would do this, as the Java API is still fairly new to me. Any suggestions? It seems like this should be an easy feat to accomplish.

from `String last_updatedArr[]`'s array result :

```
12/11/2015
12/11/2015
12/11/2015
12/11/2015
12/11/2015
13/11/2015
```

Method:

```
public String latestDate(){

    String last_updated=null;
    try {
        String last_updatedDb=null;

        String query = "SELECT Last_updated FROM Mattress";
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        ResultSet rs= pst.executeQuery();

        String last_updatedArr[]=new String[100];
        while(rs.next()){
            int i = 0;
            last_updatedDb=rs.getString("Last_updated");
            System.out.println(last_updatedDb);
            last_updatedArr[i]=last_updatedDb;
            i++;
        }

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        java.sql.Date date1,date2;
        for(int i =0;i<last_updatedArr.length;i++){

            date1 = (java.sql.Date)sdf.parse(last_updatedArr[i]);
            date2 = (java.sql.Date)sdf.parse("1/1/2010");

            if(date1.after(date2)){
                //Date1 is after Date2
                last_updated= sdf.format(date1);
            }

            if(date1.before(date2)){
                //Date1 is before Date2
                last_updated= sdf.format(date2);
            }

            if(date1.equals(date2)){
                //Date1 is equal Date2
                last_updated= sdf.format(date1);
            }
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return last_updated;

}
```

Comment: `new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime())`?

Comment: i have tried that, still doesn't work :(

Comment: Based on your code, you don't "seem" to need `java.sql.Date` as your values are just `String`s, but assuming they are stored as date types in your database, you could use `getDate` instead of `getString`, which would then return `java.sql.Date`.  Also, I'm not clear on what your actual problem is

Comment: i dont know what happen... but it seem problem solve... i change date type to string type in my database... T-T... TQ for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop resets `i` on every iteration. Move the declaration of `i` in your `while` loop. Or just use a `for` loop. Like,

```
for(int i = 0; rs.next(); i++) {
    last_updatedDb = rs.getString("Last_updated");
    System.out.println(last_updatedDb);
    last_updatedArr[i] = last_updatedDb;
}
```

**or** something like,

```
int i = 0;
while(rs.next()){
    // int i = 0;
    last_updatedArr[i] = rs.getString("Last_updated");
    System.out.println(last_updatedArr[i]);
    i++;
}

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.sql.Date date1,date2;
// reuse i from while loop...
for(i = 0; i < last_updatedArr.length; i++){
```